# How write history in a file with a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i do a long manipulation, so i want to take my history and put in a file "text.txt" then i rm the history, but it doesn't work i dont know why.

```
#!/bin/bash


while true
do
     history -r
     history >> root/history.txt
     echo "history.txt rempli" &
     echo "test automatise" >> history.txt
     rm history
    sleep 10
done
```

it  only write "test automatise", history is orange but bash tells me than he can't rm history because he doesn't know it.

I do ./test.sh &  when i want to start the scrpt.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm history` will try to delete history file or directory, it probably does not exist and will throw an error, instead clear your history with `history -c`

history does not work because it is not ran in the current shell script, you can make it work with `source` :

```
#!/bin/bash


while true
do
     history -r
     history >> root/history.txt
     echo "history.txt rempli" &
     echo "test automatise" >> history.txt
     history -c
    sleep 10
done
```

and then run

```
$ source test.sh &
```

learn more about source :https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

learn more about why history does not work without source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script